# How many symbol entries should a constant variable that declared in Cpp header have?

Tags: c++, c++11

This program is written in c++, compiled with std++0x.

Suppose I have a const declared in header file:

```
/* const.h */
#ifndef CONST_H
#define CONST_H
const int length = 5;
#endif
```

I use this const.h in my printer.h and monitor.h files.
When compiling the code, the program has 3 translation units generated, namely, main.o, printer.o and monitor.o.

The compile output is as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"monitor.d" -MT"monitor.o" -o "monitor.o" "../monitor.cpp"
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"printer.d" -MT"printer.o" -o "printer.o" "../printer.cpp"
g++  -o "constSym"  ./main.o ./monitor.o ./printer.o
```

My question is how many symbol entries of "length" should this program have in the symbol table of the final executable?
My initial thought is 3, since we have 3 translation units and length variable is in internal linkage. So each translation unit should have 1 such entry and they are in different address.

However, I tried it out and find that there is only one such symbol.

Please explain that where my thought is wrong and why it only has one symbol.

Comment: The c++faq tag is for questions that are asked an linked to often. Please don't add it to your question yourself without a reason.

Comment: How did you try it out, whether there are one or more symbols?

Comment: @AkosBannerth I use eclipse IDE.I created a C++ project. The compile commands emitted from eclipse are shown in my post. There is only one "length" symbol shown in symbol table. It is in . rodata section.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption of internal linkage, yielding one instance of a `const` variable per `#include` is incorrect; the result you're getting (one symbol) is correct.

If however you declare `length` as non-const, and `static`, there will be a separate symbol generated for each TU that `#include`s `const.h`.

(This would not be  something you'd typically want in production, and any code (function) based on this variable, defined in `const.h` would be liable of violating the [One Definition Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), since it would would be referring to a different symbol in each TU that includes it.)

Also note that declaring `length` as `const` makes it implicitly `static`.

Comment: I was using c++ and as you mentioned, in C++, constant values default to internal linkage. Just wondering why my assumption "length variable is internal linkage" is not correct?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake; fixed it now.

Comment: In short words, the id has external storage class. this is the major difference between static and extern storage; the former is module wide unique, while the later is globally unique.